# How to remove excess space added with \n

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the space between the `<fieldset>`'s in the following example? Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rFpP/).

[image: a]

**HTML**

```
<!-- Displays bad, but HTML looks good -->
<fieldset>test</fieldset>
<fieldset>test</fieldset>

<!-- Displays good, but HTML looks bad -->
<fieldset>test</fieldset><fieldset>test</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

fieldset
{
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I'd like to be able to leave space between the `<fieldset>`'s in the HTML code, since their contents are quite long. But I need them to display right next to eachother.

Comment: just float them instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to remove any spaces between `inline-block` (or `inline`) tags.

You can use comments for better readability:

```
<fieldset>test</fieldset><!--
--><fieldset>test</fieldset>
```

There is no CSS solution which can be 100% reliable.

EDIT: it doesn't seem it's the case but some template engines provide this behaviour, like twig's [`spaceless`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html)

Comment: To be honest, this is what I've ended up doing... kinda, I just put up with the mangly HTML. Reason being, the `float` caused more trouble than it was worth when viewed on a large TV screen. I've accepted this answer now instead.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2rFpP/6/)**

How about `float: left;`:

**CSS:**

```
fieldset {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! One caveat though, was that I previously had `form { text-align: center }`. I had to also add `display: inline-block` to `form`, to keep it centered on the page.

Answer (score -1):

A different solution is to put the fieldsets in a DIV container and set the font-size to 0 using CSS for that container. Then, of course, set the font-size of the field-sets back to whatever you need it to.

Setting the font-size to 0 on parent container basically removes the white-space between inline-block elements of that container.

Comment: Some browsers (Chrome, Opera) enforce a minimum font-size.  This method does *not* play nicely if you're using relative font sizes (if you're still using px for your font-size, you're doing it wrong).